JpaSystemException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance
Case:
Entity declaration:
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Foo> foos = Lists.newArrayList();

This block
            user.getFoos().clear();
// instantiate `foos`, eg: final List<Foo> foos = myService.createFoos(bla, bla);
            user.setFoos(foos);

generates this error:
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.github.lalou.jonathan.blabla.User.foos


Fix:
Do not use setFoos() ; rather, after clearing, use addAll().
In other words, replace:
            user.getFoos().clear();
            user.setFoos(foos);

with
            user.getFoos().clear();
            user.getFoos().addAll(foos);


Finally fixed my problem, note i need to attach the user to the foos before adding
